# Access GoPro camera on the command line (Linux)

Tags: linux, fedora, gopro

I can access my GoPro camera via the GUI when it's plugged in to my Fedora laptop - it appears as StillImage (under Devices), but I don't seem to be able to access it via the command line. Pressing CTRL+L gives the location as "gphoto2://[usb:003,023]/". However, typing ls gphoto2://[usb:003,023]/ in a terminal returns:

```
ls: cannot access gphoto2://[usb:003,023]/: No such file or directory
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you install a new firmware ?   I've recently lost the ability to mount a gopro 3+ silver in linux.  It shows up as a USB device in lsusb, but not as a scsi storage device, like it used to.

Answer (score 2):

Those “StillImage” devices are mounted by [GVfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GVfs). You will usually find such devices mounted under `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/gvfs` where `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` is typically `/run/user/$UID`. For example, I see my GoPro camera mounted here:

```
/run/user/1000/gvfs/gphoto2:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C004%5D
```

If `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` should not be set for you for some reason, you could also try to find the GVfs mount location with `grep gvfs /etc/mtab` which yields the following for me:

```
gvfsd-fuse /run/user/1000/gvfs fuse.gvfsd-fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,user=chriki 0 0
```